# How Do I setup a backend such as node.js/express with react(using vite) also how do I deploy, do I use vite's commands or node's

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(LOOK AT TITLE) I am a beginner in react and I wanted to use Vite.JS I know nothing about Node.js but I want to learn it so I need to connect them. Please let me know! also how do I deploy, should I use vite's commands As I would do without a backend or are there special commands, should I be in the backend folder When deploying? That's all if you know any answers please Hit me up!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For backend configuration, from the official vite [documentaion](https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html);

In your Vite config.js file,overwrite its content with the following:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: './src/main.jsx',
    },
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:5000/", // the address that u serve in the backend 
    },
  },
})
```

> This is to set the bundle’s entry point to src/main.jsx instead of the default index.html.
> Inside your public folder, there is the index.html, or it might be inside the src directory depending with your vite-js version. Edit its contents to point the main.jsx file path.

```js
<script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
```

That's it.